# Convertir un float o un entero en string en c++

Tags: c++, string, conversión-de-tipos, float

Quería saber una forma sencilla de **convertir** una variable `float` o `int` en tipo de dato `string` en `C++`. Porque busque en varios lados y hablan de usar `sprintf`, de la libreria `stdio.h` pero no funciona con `string` sino con `char`.

Por ejemplo, a un número *1564.53* lo quiero pasar a *"1564.53"* pero quiero que ese `string` no se pierda sino que se pueda guardar en una variable de tipo `string`.

Para lo que necesito es devolver un saldo en formato moneda, es decir con el signo pesos $ al principio seguido del valor del saldo, pero este está en `float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A partir de `C++ 11`, la biblioteca estándar de `C++` proporciona la función [`std::to_string(arg)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) con varios tipos compatibles para `arg`, y si puede aceptar el formato predeterminado `(%f)`.**

---

O como alternativa puedes usar `ostringstream` desde `<sstream>`, aunque puede que no sea la forma más fácil.

```
#include <sstream>
std::string Convert (float number){
    std::ostringstream buff;
    buff<<number;
    return buff.str();   
}
```

> Fuente: [Conversión de Flotante a Cadena](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/146718/conversion-from-float-to-string)

---

Además Si está de acuerdo con Boost, [lexical_cast <>](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) es una alternativa conveniente:

```
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(tuFloat);
```

Las alternativas eficientes son, por ejemplo, [FastFormat](http://www.fastformat.org/) o simplemente las funciones estilo C.

Comment: Me interesa la primer opción, es lo que busco algo simple,pero para implementarla como lo hago?                                                       
`string CuentaBancaria::formatoMoneda(){
 string s = std::string to_string( float saldo ); return s;
}`Pero me da error de esta forma

Comment: @EmilianoCalvacho debería ser `std::string s = std::to_string(saldo);`.

Comment: @Xam gracias. El problema era que no tenía `C++ version 11`

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
int Number = 123;
string String = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << Number) )->str();
```

Comment: Me da el siguiente error: `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::ostringstream {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>}'|'`

Answer (score 1):

> J. Rodríguez

Como lo dice el colega. Funiona perfecto

De esta forma lo puedes usar.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


std::string Convert (float number){
    std::ostringstream buff;
    buff<<number;
    return buff.str();
}

int main(){
    float Num;
    cout << "Ingrese un numero : ";
    cin >> Num;

    cout << endl << "Numero digitado es: " << Num;
    // Puedes hacerlo asi, aunque no quieres eso creo
    cout << endl << "Numero digitado es: $" << Num;

    // Ahora convertir
    string NumeroString = Convert(Num);
    cout << endl << "String :" << NumeroString;

    NumeroString = "$" + NumeroString;
    cout << endl << "String :" << NumeroString;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo!