# Intentando insertar pixeles en una cola

Tags: c++

Tengo un problemilla a la hora de insertar un pixel en una cola.
Lo que quiero es insertar el punto no lo que tiene la imagen en ese punto
Gracias

Lo que tengo es esto:

```
queue <int> cola;
for (int i = imagen.FirstRow()+1; i <=imagen.LastRow()-1; i++) {
        for (int j = imagen.FirstCol() + 1; j <imagen.LastCol()-1; j++) {
              if (imagen(i, j) <= 5)
                  cola.push(???) // aqui es donde quiero insertar el punto
                  cola.push(imagen(i,j)) // esto es el valor del punto
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tengo un problemilla a la hora de insertar un pixel en una cola. Lo que quiero es insertar el punto no lo que tiene la imagen en ese punto Gracias

De que forma quieres guardar el punto: En un int ? String ?

## Por ejemplo:

- Puedes guardar el valor de i en un campo y el valor de j en el otro campo de la cola.
- La otra opcion seria concatenar el punto i y j, convirtiendo a string, se concatena y por ultimo guardas en una cola de string.

Podria ser así:

```
std::string Convert (float number){
    std::ostringstream buff;
    buff<<number;
    return buff.str();
}

queue <int> cola;
queue <string> Puntocola;
for (int i = imagen.FirstRow()+1; i <=imagen.LastRow()-1; i++) {
    for (int j = imagen.FirstCol() + 1; j <imagen.LastCol()-1; j++) {
          if (imagen(i, j) <= 5)
              string Imagepunto = Convert(i) + "," + Convert(j);
              // aqui es donde quiero insertar el punto
              cola.push(Imagepunto)
              cola.push(imagen(i,j)) // esto es el valor del punto
    }
}
```

> En caso de int tendria esta opcion.
>   Creas una clase con atributos x , y, en los cuales guardas el pixel.

```
public class PixelImage{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    // Constructor 
    public PixelImage(int px, int py){
        x = px;
        y = py;
    }
}

// Creas la cola tipo PixelImage. Creo que esto seria en otra clase sabiendo que es POO
PixelCola punto; 
queue <PixelImage> PixelCola;
queue <string> cola;
for (int i = imagen.FirstRow()+1; i <=imagen.LastRow()-1; i++) {
    for (int j = imagen.FirstCol() + 1; j <imagen.LastCol()-1; j++) {
          if (imagen(i, j) <= 5)
              // Creo que i es x y J es y
              punto = new PixelImage(i,j);
              PixelCola.push(punto);
              cola.push(imagen(i,j)) // esto es el valor del punto
    }
}
```

> [Queue of array of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408776/queue-of-array-of-characters)
>
> [Convertir un float o un entero en string en c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157976/convertir-un-float-o-un-entero-en-string-en-c/158012#158012)

Comment: Es buena la respuesta! Gracias!! Pero me gustaria guardar como Int

Comment: Realize una modificaciòn a la respuesta. Espero que te funcione y logres adaptar a lo que deseas, por cierto no es necesario tener dos colas, solo puedes agregar el otro atributo a proceso de tipo string y pasas por parametro igual.